# Simple, statically-linked encryption program

Tags: linux, encryption, bash

I am looking for an easy encryption program, usable from the linux command line. Preferably a single static binary. I tried scrypt (tarsnap), but it prompts for a password with no way to input as a flag. This means it cannot be used from a script.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure why you believe it cannot be used from a script. Check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917630/is-it-possible-to-use-the-scrypt-command-to-encrypt-all-the-files-in-a-folder) and its detailed answer. It depends on the [`<<<` operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean). Also, a standard way to automate tasks which require user input is the [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) program, which likely already comes installed on your system and is easily acquired if not.

Comment: Oh, I had meant to link to a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219416/how-to-use-a-linux-expect-script-to-enter-answer-a-prompt-for-password) for possible tips and further reading on `expect`, though the Wikipedia entry actually does have some nice examples already.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `PGP/gpg`:

```
# Encrypt
gpg --output file.gpg --encrypt --recipient your@self.com file

# Decrypt
gpg --output file --decrypt file.gpg
```

Before you can do that, you need to create a key pair and import it to your keyring. See the manual on how to do it: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/book1.html